# Rotate Text by 90 degrees with GDI

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, gdi

I want to draw text to a GDI Surface and rotate this text by 90 degrees counter clockwise. I would prefer to use DrawText to draw the text because it supports carriage return. I tried to use a font with lfEscapement (see the code below) but the line is not rotated - one line gets rendered over the other. Is there any possibility to rotate the text? Or to render without rotation and rotate the whole device context?

---

Normal text layout:

[image]

---

Rotated (desired result):

[image]

```
    case WM_PAINT:
    {
        hdc = BeginPaint(hWnd, &ps);

        LOGFONT lf = {0};
        HANDLE hFont;
        ZeroMemory(&lf, sizeof(LOGFONT));

        lf.lfWeight = FW_NORMAL;
        lstrcpy(lf.lfFaceName, _T("Tahoma"));
        lf.lfEscapement = 90;
        lf.lfHeight = 30;
        hFont = CreateFontIndirect (&lf);
        hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject (ps.hdc, hFont);

        RECT RectBody = {10,lf.lfHeight+10,::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)-10,::GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)-lf.lfHeight-20};
        {
            ScopedLock lock(me->m_mutex);
            DrawText (ps.hdc, me->GetMessageString().c_str(), (int)me->GetMessageString().length(), &RectBody, 0);
        }

        hFont = (HFONT)SelectObject (ps.hdc, hFont);
        DeleteObject (hFont);

        EndPaint(hWnd, &ps);
        break;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   lf.lfEscapement = 90;
```

That should be 900 to get the text vertical, units are 0.1 degrees.

Your plan to let DrawText take care of the line breaks is going to fall flat I'm afraid.  I could not convince it to align the text properly.  It aligns on the last line, not the first.  Some code to play with:

```
    wchar_t* msg = L"Hello\r\nworld";
    RECT rcMeasure = {0, 0, 400, 0};
    DrawTextEx(hdc, msg, -1, &rcMeasure, DT_CALCRECT, 0);
    RECT rcDraw = {10, 30, 10 + rcMeasure.bottom - rcMeasure.top, 30 + rcMeasure.right - rcMeasure.left };
    FillRect(hdc, &rcDraw, (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+2));
    SetTextAlign(hdc, TA_TOP | TA_CENTER);
    DrawTextEx(hdc, msg, -1, &rcDraw, DT_BOTTOM, 0);
```

I think I tried all alignment options.

Answer (score 0):

I have the impression that this link answers your question, but using ExtTextOut, and not DrawText

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI/textrotation.aspx

it's not GDI+ it's MFC but they are close.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I tried TA_BASELINE with very strange results (the Text gets rendered on top of the screen). I seen the articel on codeproject. The only problem I see is that I need to handle carriage returns/line length myself.

Comment: Just another suggestion, at this link on codeguru, there are examples for rotating bitmaps. You could draw your text horizontaly in a bitmap of a compatible DC to your main DC, then use it rotated in your main DC.
http://www.codeguru.com/cpp/g-m/bitmap/specialeffects/article.php/c1743