# How to draw rotated text with ScriptTextOut?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, uniscribe

How do I draw rotated text using the [`ScriptTextOut`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/usp10/nf-usp10-scripttextout) function?
I tried both [`Graphics::SetTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/Gdiplusgraphics/nf-gdiplusgraphics-graphics-settransform) and [`SetWorldTransform`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-setworldtransform) and they didn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/38758804/4603670 for rotating text from `TextOut`, `ScriptTextOut` is the same.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Apparently I was missing the call to `SetGraphicsMode`